# Merging two matrices of different dimension in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices `A` and `B` in Matlab. A has dimension `mx6`, e.g.

```
A=[  1     1     1     1   |  1     0;
     1     1     1     2   |  1     0;
     1     1     1     3   |  1     0;
     1     1     1     4   |  1     0;
     1     2     3     2   |  1     0;
     1     2     3     3   |  1     0;
     1     2     3     4   |  1     0]
```

`B` has dimension `nx6`, e.g.

```
B=[  1     1     1     1   |  1     1;
     1     2     3     1   |  1     1]
```

I want to merge `A` and `B` and create the matrix `C` following these steps without using loops:

1) Consider `B(i,1:4)`; if there exists `j` such that `A(j,1:4)` is equal to `B(i,1:4)` [this can happen for at most one `j`] then `C(i,:)=[B(i,1:4) A(j,5)+B(i,5) A(j,6)+B(i,6)]`. Do this for all `i=1,...,n`.

2) Fill the remaining rows of `C` with the rows of `A` and `B` that cannot be matched according to step 1).

In the example

```
C=[  1     1     1     1   |  2     1;  %Step 1) above
   ------------------------------------
     1     1     1     2   |  1     0;  %Step 2) above
     1     1     1     3   |  1     0;  %firstly rows from A
     1     1     1     4   |  1     0;
     1     2     3     2   |  1     0;
     1     2     3     3   |  1     0;
     1     2     3     4   |  1     0; 
     1     2     3     1   |  1     1]  %lastly rows from B
```

My attempt using loops:

```
%STEP 1
     for i=1:size(B,1)
            for j=1:size(A,1)
                if all(B(i,1:4)==A(j,1:4),2)
                   C(i,:)=[B(i,1:4) A(j,5)+B(i,5) A(j,6)+B(i,6)]
                end
            end
        end



 %STEP 2


  C=[ C; A(logical(1-ismember(A(:,1:4), B(:,1:4),'rows')),:)];
  C=[ C; B(logical(1-ismember(B(:,1:4), A(:,1:4),'rows')),:)];
```

Comment: Have you written code to try to do this? What problem are you having?

Comment: I did not specify that I don't want to use loops. I have no idea on how to answer the question without using loops. Just edited!

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite easy using a combination of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).  `unique` works by giving you an output matrix where all of the duplicate entries are removed.  This will work nicely when it comes to playing with `A` and `B`.

Simply concatenate `A` and `B` together into a single consolidated matrix, then use `unique` with the first 4 columns and assign each row of this truncated matrix a unique ID.  The third output of `unique` will give you that ID and if you want to know which ID corresponds to what row, that comes out of the first output of `unique`, where each row of the output gives you the ID that it corresponds to.

You would use the `'rows'` and `'stable'` flag to ensure that we look at each row rather than each individual element in the matrix and with the `'stable'` flag, we assign the IDs based on when we encounter a unique row from the start (top) to the finish (bottom).  If you didn't put the `'stable'` flag, it would **sort** the rows internally, then assign the IDs starting from the top to the bottom of this sorted list.

If you want to achieve your desired output, you must use `'stable'`.  Once you find these IDs, use `accumarray` twice on the fifth and sixth columns respectively and apply a separate sum and combine the results together.  `accumarray` works by giving a set of IDs or keys, and for each ID/key, there's an output value associated with this key.  You group all of the values that share the same key, and do something to each group.  In our case, we would apply `accumarray` twice where the first set of output values come from the fifth column, and the second set of output values come from the sixth column.  The default behaviour with `accumarray` is to **sum** all of the values that belong to the same group, which is what you wanted.

The output of `accumarray` in our case will be a single column vector that is as long as the total number of unique IDs that was generated in the first step with `unique`.  You do this for the fifth and sixth columns separately, then to get your final matrix, simply combine the first output of `unique` as well as the two `accumarray` outputs into a single matrix to finally get the output.

Something like this:

```
%// Your data
A=[  1     1     1     1     1     0;
1     1     1     2     1     0;
1     1     1     3     1     0;
1     1     1     4     1     0;
1     2     3     2     1     0;
1     2     3     3     1     0;
1     2     3     4     1     0];
B=[  1     1     1     1     1     1;
1     2     3     1     1     1];

%// Solution
[cols,~,id] = unique([A(:,1:4); B(:,1:4)], 'rows', 'stable');
out = accumarray(id, [A(:,5); B(:,5)]);
out2 = accumarray(id, [A(:,6); B(:,6)]);
final = [cols out out2];
```

This is our output:

```
final =

     1     1     1     1     2     1
     1     1     1     2     1     0
     1     1     1     3     1     0
     1     1     1     4     1     0
     1     2     3     2     1     0
     1     2     3     3     1     0
     1     2     3     4     1     0
     1     2     3     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using a loop. However, i'm not quite sure this will be faster than a loop.

```
ind = 1:size(B,1);

[indA, indA_true] = ismember(A(:,1:4),B(:,1:4),'rows');

indB = indA_true(find(indA_true));

C = [A(indA,1:4), A(indA,5:6) + B((indB),5:6)];

C = [C; A(~indA,:); B(~ismember(ind',indB,'rows'),:)];
```