# How to merge two matrices of different dimensions in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I like to merge two matrices of different dimensions in MATLAB without using loops as I have done it with loops.

The image below shows what I want to achieve.

[image]

I also tried this link, but this is not what I want: [Merging two matrices of different dimension in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299418/merging-two-matrices-of-different-dimension-in-matlab)

Here is my attempt to do it with loops:

```
A=zeros(2,9)-1;
B=ones(6,3);
disp(A);
disp(B);
C=zeros(max(size(A,1),size(B,1)),max(size(A,2),size(B,2)));

for i=1:1:size(A,1)
    C(i,:)=A(i,:);
end
for i=1:1:size(B,2)
    C(:,i)=B(:,i);
end
disp(C);
```

The desired output should be like this:

```
A:
    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1

B:
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1

C:
     1     1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
     1     1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

However, I am looking for a better approach without using loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done purely by indexing.  First declare your output matrix `C` as you did before, then replace the first two rows of `C` with `A`, then replace the first three columns of `C` with `B`:

```
%// Your code
A=zeros(2,9)-1;
B=ones(6,3);
C=zeros(max(size(A,1),size(B,1)),max(size(A,2),size(B,2)));

%// New code
C(1:size(A,1),:) = A;
C(:,1:size(B,2)) = B;
```

We get:

```
>> C

C =

     1     1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
     1     1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: how can i generalize this value of 2 & 3 on the basis of matrix dimension?C(1:2,:) = A;
C(:,1:3) = B; if i take min size of A & B respectively will that be correct in general?

Comment: @ShvetChakra I've edited the code to make this more general.  This will first examine the total number of rows in `A` and replace those rows in `C`. After, we look at the total number of columns in `B` and replace those columns in `C`.  There is no error checking and so you need to make sure that the total number of rows in `A` and the total number of columns in `B` can fit in the right dimensions for `C`, but you ensure this when you create the initial `C` matrix in any case.